# How to reference a particular label

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to create keypad interface that enters the numbers into labels. It is easier to think along the lines of a keypad where you enter your 4 digit pin to enter, much like when you turn on a locked iOS device.

I have four labels, which will show the numbers once typed. I have 12 buttons which contain numbers (plus a cancel and delete button). Each button has a tag assigned to it.
on clicking the button, I want that tag to be entered as the text to the next empty label.

What I need to do is to reference the next empty label in the setPin function.  Am I going about this the wrong way or is there just a bit that I am missing?  A trimmed down version of my code is below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setCurrField:1];

    // BUILD A VIEW TO CONTAIN THE LOGIN PANEL
    UIView *pinView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 400, 500)];
    pinView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // CREATE BUTTONS
    int nPos = 1;
    int leftPos;
    int topPos = 134;

    while (nPos <= 12) 
    {
        leftPos = (nPos%3 == 1) ? 19 : leftPos + 113 + 12;
        topPos = (nPos%3 == 1) ? topPos + 61 + 10 : topPos;

        // BUILD THE BUTTONS AND ADD TO THE PAGE
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setTag:nPos];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(setPin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(leftPos, topPos, 113, 61)];
        [btn setBackgroundColor: [UIColor darkGrayColor]];

        NSString *btnLabel;
        if(nPos <= 9)
        {
            btnLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", nPos];
        }
        else
        {
            switch (nPos) {
                case 10:
                    btnLabel = @"Cancel";
                    break;

                case 11:
                    btnLabel = @"0";
                    break;

                case 12:
                    btnLabel = @"Delete";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        [btn setTitle: btnLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [pinView addSubview:btn];

        nPos++;
    }

    // CREATE THE TEXTBOXES
    UILabel *char1Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19, 65, 83, 91)];
    UILabel *char2Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(113, 65, 83, 91)];
    UILabel *char3Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(207, 65, 83, 91)];
    UILabel *char4Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(301, 65, 83, 91)];

    [pinView addSubview:char1Label];
    [pinView addSubview:char2Label];
    [pinView addSubview:char3Label];
    [pinView addSubview:char4Label];

    [[self view] addSubview:pinView];

}

-(void)setPin:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(sender.tag <= 9 || sender.tag == 11)
    {
        [--charLabel[self currField]Label-- setText:[sender tag]];
        [self currField++];
    }
    elseif(sender.tag == 12) 
    {
        [self currField--];
        [--charLabel[self currField]Label-- setText:@""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to put each label into an NSMutableArray (as well as onto your view). Then to get each label in `setPin` you could do:

```
UILabel *label = [labelArray objectAtIndex:currField];
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", sender.tag]];
currField++;
```

Comment: I am always impressed by how quickly questions are answered on this forum.  Thanks for your help guys. I think the concept of putting the labels in an array makes the most sense to me, so I think I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold onto the references to the textLabels, perhaps as a property to the class you are in.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray* textLabels; // Choose a more descriptive name than this

...

self.textLabels = @[ char1Label, char2Label, char3Label, char4Label ];


...

- (UILabel*) nextEmptyLabel {

    for (UILabel* label in self.TextLabels) 
    {
         NSString* trimmedText = [label.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
         if ([trimmedText length] == 0) {
             return label;
         }
    }

    return nil;  // No non empty label found
}
```

Comment: Might want to modify your length checking - `[[label.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length]`